# bring data from 2 tables mysql and display them

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables. Table **user_job(id, title, expires)** and table **user_job_business(id, title, expires)**. The first table holds jobs posted by users and the second table holds jobs posted by companies. All I want is to display all jobs from users and companies in the same page the one under the other each job in its own table. How can I modify my code to do this? This is my code dipslaying jobs from users one under the other.

```
<?php

$get_myjobs = mysql_query("select * from `user_job` ");

while($run_job = mysql_fetch_array($get_myjobs )){

  $user_job_id = $run_job['id'];    
  $user_job_title = $run_job['title'];  
  $user_job_expires = $run_job['expires'];

  echo"<table> <td>$user_job_title</td> <td>$user_job_expires</td>  </table>";

}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use union or union all:

```
$get_myjobs = mysql_query("select id, title, expires from `user_job` union all select id, title, expires from `user_job_business`");
```

the difference between union and union all, union remove redundancy or repeated rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can use union in your case, but I would recommend you reorganize your structure and make 1 table instead of 2. It will give you better schema and good performance.

it | title | expires | role_id

where role_id - identifier to user,company